# Is it pythonic to declare two variables at once with multiple equal signs?

Tags: python

Doing something like

```
a = b = 5

a
Out[63]: 5

b
Out[64]: 5
```

It seems to work without any problems, I can't imagine any drawbacks. I can't find any example of this out there, nor directions on whether this should be used. Are there reasons to not do this?

Comment: That is *semantically* different than two separate assignment statements. That means those variables are referring *to the same object*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With this code, you won't run into any issues since you're assigning a number, and numbers are immutable.

Compare that to when a mutable value is used though:

```
a = b = []  # Mutable list
a.append(1)  # Mutate mutable list
print(a, b)  # [1] [1]  # Oops
```

So, be careful with this. Only use it if both variables referring to the same object isn't problematic.

---

I'll clarify though, it isn't the fact that the object is mutable that's the problem, it's the fact that *as* a mutable object, it's capable of being mutated, and that mutation is problematic. It's perfectly fine to use this way if you "treat the lists as immutable":

```
a = b = []
# Some other code
a = [1]  # Maybe these are conditional reassignments in a loop or something
b = [2]

print(a, b)  # [1] [2]
```

Although, if you're using lists like this, you'd likely be better off using a tuple or other immutable object instead.

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out by @juanpa.arrivillaga in the comments, this results in both variables sharing the *same object*.  In your example this won't matter, but there are cases where it will.

```
a = b = []
a.append(1)
print(b)
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends, if its a simple assignment to integers, then it works.
But this fails for others. Lets say you instantiate to a list

```py
a = b = [2,3]
```

Now this actually create one object on memory, and both `a` and `b` share that.
So if you change the value of `a`, it will be reflected on `b`. Which is not what you want. So its better to stick with the one assignment per line.

```py
>> a[1] = 0
>> print(b)
[2,0]
```